# Using get_dummies to create a Simple Recommender System - Cold Start

Tags: python, beginner, numpy, pandas

**Question:** was using `get_dummies` a good choice for converting categorical strings?

I used `get_dummies` to convert categorical variables into dummy / indicator variables for a cold start recommender system. It's only using category type information and some basic limited choices.

The code works and the output seems good. This is my first data science project, which is for fun. I kind of put this together from reading documentation and searching Stack Overflow. I plan on making it a hybrid recommender system soon by adding sentiment analysis and topic classification. Both of which I also recently finished.

To check another character just Input a different character name in `userInput`. The full notebook and Excel sheet for import are on [my GitHub](https://github.com/taylorjohn/Simple_RecSys/blob/master/dnd-rec.ipynb).

I would be grateful if someone could comment on whether or not I was able to achieve the following goals (and of course if not, what I can improve):

- Code structure,
- Style and readability: Is the code comprehensible?
- Are there any bad practices?

These are the attributes in my code:

- Character's name (must be unique)
- herotype (must be one of following choices)

  - Bard
  - Sorcerer
  - Paladin
  - Rogue
  - Druid
  - Sorcerer
- weapons (can have one or multiple of following choices)

  - Dagger
  - sling
  - club
  - light crossbow
  - battleaxe
  - Greataxe
- spells (can have one or multiple of following choices)

  - Transmutation
  - Enchantment
  - Necromancy
  - Abjuration
  - Conjuration
  - Evocation

## Input and Output

**Get Another Recommendation**
You just input the username 'Irv' to another one like 'Zed Ryley' etc

```
userInput = [
            {'name':'Irv', 'rating':1}
```

**The results**
come back formatted like this

```
    name    herotype    weapons     spells
28  Irv     Sorcerer    light crossbow  Conjuration
9   yac     Sorcerer    Greataxe    Conjuration, Evocation, Transmutation
18  Traubon Durthane    Sorcerer    light crossbow  Evocation, Transmutation, Necromancy
8   wuc     Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
1   niem    Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
23  Zed Ryley   Sorcerer    sling   Evocation
```

**For comparison**

Here are the scores which show how it ranks the results.

```
In [5]:

recommendationTable_df.head(6)

Out[5]:

28    1.000000
9     0.666667
18    0.666667
8     0.666667
1     0.666667
23    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

## Code

```
#imports 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('dnd-dataframe.xlsx', sheet_name=0, usecols=['name', 'weapons','herotype','spells'])
df.head(30)
```

```
dummies1 = df['weapons'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
dummies2 = df['spells'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
dummies3 = df['herotype'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')

genre_data = pd.concat([df, dummies1,dummies2, dummies3], axis=1)

userInput = [
            {'name':'Irv', 'rating':1}   #Their is no rating system being used so by default rating is set to 1
         ] 
inputname = pd.DataFrame(userInput)

inputId = df[df['name'].isin(inputname['name'].tolist())]

#Then merging it so we can get the name. It's implicitly merging spells it by name.
inputname = pd.merge(inputId, inputname)

#Dropping information we won't use from the input dataframe
inputname = inputname.drop('weapons',1).drop('spells',1).drop('herotype',1)

#Filtering out the names from the input
username = genre_data[genre_data['name'].isin(inputname['name'].tolist())]

#Resetting the index to avoid future issues
username = username.reset_index(drop=True)

#Dropping unnecessary issues due to save memory and to avoid issues
userGenreTable = username.drop('name',1).drop('weapons',1).drop('spells',1).drop('herotype',1)

#Dot product to get weights
userProfile = userGenreTable.transpose().dot(inputname['rating'])

genreTable = genre_data.copy()
genreTable = genreTable.drop('name',1).drop('weapons',1).drop('spells',1).drop('herotype',1)
```

```
#Multiply the genres by the weights and then take the weighted average
recommendationTable_df = ((genreTable*userProfile).sum(axis=1))/(userProfile.sum())

#Sort our recommendations in descending order
recommendationTable_df = recommendationTable_df.sort_values(ascending=False)

#df.loc[df.index.isin(recommendationTable_df.head(3).keys())] #adjust the value of 3 here

df.loc[recommendationTable_df.head(6).index, :]
```

Answer (score 1):

The dummies{1,2,3} identifiers are kind of OK, but not very mnemonic.

Actually, there's no need to invent new names at all, we can go the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) anonymous route.

```
dummies = [df[col].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
           for col in ['weapons', 'spells', 'herotype']]
genre_data = pd.concat([df] + dummies, axis=1)
```

Now that we have the dummies,
this would be an appropriate time
to drop those three source columns.

---

[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you spell it `user_input`.

We're accumulating a bunch of stale variables
in the global namespace, like `user_input` and `dummies`.
I recommend you define the occasional helper function.
That gives no-longer-needed temp variables a chance
to go out of scope when the function exits.

---

[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
We seem to be doing some repeated operations:
dropping three source columns, checking `inputname`.

Maybe we *need* a separate `username` dataframe.
But maybe we could have just added the occasional
column to `genre_data` instead?

---

The `# comments` are a bit more chatty than my own style,
but that's fine; I imagine you find them helpful.
I will note that *naming* a helper function goes a
long way toward explaining the
[Single Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
of a few lines of code. And if more explanation is needed,
there's lots of room for that in the helper's `"""docstring"""`.

Also, a small helper function is a function that is easily
[unit tested](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).

---

zomg, we're `.drop()`ing those three source columns yet again?!?
Couldn't we have banished them just once, near the beginning?

---

The identifier `recommendationTable_df` is an abomination.
Please don't do that. Pick an approach to naming, perhaps
the pascal / JS `recommendationTableDf`, or since this
is Python, perhaps the PEP-8 `recommendation_table_df`.
But mixing them won't help to improve the readability
of the code.

---

You have a commented expression containing `.head(3)` - I'm sure
it was helpful during development, but it's time to remove it
from final production code, now.

The last line includes the
[magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
`6`. Please give it a name.
Often this is most conveniently done in a function signature:

```
def get_final_recommendations(num_recs=6):
    return df.loc[recommendationTable_df.head(num_recs).index, :]
```

---

Overall, I can see there was a clear emphasis on trying
to make the code readable and maintainable.

("Maintenance" means new features and bug fixes.)

I would be reluctant to hand this off,
in its current state,
for some new hire to perform a maintenance task.
The maintainer would probably need to discuss things
with the original author.

Frozen in / out data, unit tests, and small helpers
would help to improve the maintainability situation.